# Could not find a declaration file for third party modules - how to declare and resolve these errors

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, typescript-typings, vue-cli

I am working on a project with typescript (generated with vue cli 3.0).

When I import third party modules, I get errors such as:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-slider-component'. 
'/home/wahid/Development/tealvalley-app/node_modules/vue-slider- 
component/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

What is the correct way to resolve these kind of issues? The types are not defined in the @types package, so if I were to define them myself, where do I keep it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the correct way to resolve these kind of issues?

Create a file [`vendor.d.ts`](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/migrating.html) that has:

```
declare module 'vue-slider-component';
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occured because of vue-slider-component has been generated in JavaScript.

To avoid the issue I just replace it by the standard require():

```js
const vue-slider-component= require('vue-slider-component');
// import { vue-slider-component} from 'vue-slider-component'
```

Thanks :slight_smile: