# How to install vue-owl-carousel properly via npm in VUE JS Project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, owl-carousel

I have a vue-js web app and I want to install 3rd-party modules like `vue-owl-carousel`. I followed this guide [here](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/add-a-slider-to-a-vue-app-with-the-vue-owl-carousel-library-2373c7601ade). I did the steps but when I tried calling the import function:

```
import carousel from "vue-owl-carousel";
```

It  says that `Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-owl-carousel' . 'file-path' implicitly has an 'any' type.` It says that I need to add `vendor.d.ts` file in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50360164/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-third-party-modules-how-to-declare-and-r/50361987#50361987).

But nothing seems to work. Any ideas how to implement this one? I'm calling my owl carousel into the component like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="bottom">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="btm1_content">
        <h5>Our Process Flow</h5>
        <div class="btm1_mainbox">
          <carousel>
            <div
              class="btm1_box"
              v-for="process in processes"
              :key="process.id"
            >
              <h4>{{ process.title }}</h4>
              <p>{{ process.content }}</p>
            </div>
          </carousel>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import carousel from "vue-owl-carousel";

export default {
  name: "bottom",
  components: { carousel },
  data() {
    return {
      processes: [
        {
          id: "1",
          title: "Process Title",
          content:
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          title: "Process Title",
          content:
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**EDIT**

Here is my `vue.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                additionalData: `@import "@/assets/scss/app.scss";`,
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: Can you share these files if you have them? `vue.config.js` and `ts.config.js`. I just tried following the same tutorial as you on a fresh vue app and it works fine so it must be something in there.

Comment: @JesseRezaKhorasanee I've made an edit on it. I have no ts.config.js file.

Comment: Do you have any `.ts` files in your project?